# Subsetting if element is equal to one of the elements of a vector

Tags: r, subset

Imagine a dataset like this

Dataset

```
Var1 Var2 
a    apple
b    banana
c    table
d    apple
e    banana
f    table
g    banana
```

I have a vector like this

```
x<-c("apple","banana")
```

I want to subset the dataset and obtain a dataset that only has elements which Var2 is equal to ONE of the elements of x.

so that the output should be a dataset like

```
Var1 Var2 
a    apple
b    banana
d    apple
e    banana
g    banana
```

I know the question might seem trivial, but I can't find an answer on the web.

Comment: `df[df$Var2 %in% x,]`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sotos, just didn't think about this syntax. Thanks PoGibas for the editing too

Answer (score 0):

```
## lets say dataset df , has var1, var2
df[df$Var2 %in% x, ]
## %in% is vectorized, so it will essentially give a T/F for every x%in%y
```

Hence when you do data.frame[True/Fase, ] , it gives all rows of DF that have TRUE.